# Can't bevel an inverted edge using bevel tool

Tags: bevel

Im creating this steel part for a trailer chassis.
I used the bevel tool with sucess for edge 1, now I want to do the same with edge 2 but no sucess. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: That should work. What is happening when you do it? Also consider to load an image with the edge visible or upload your blend file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, mesh had too much double vertices.
Went into edit mode (TAB), vertex selected, selected all vertices (A) and W (Remove Doubles).